# Bind ctrl-p in doom emacs

Tags: evil, doom, multiple-cursors

I am trying to map a key to `C-p` and unfortunately the `evil-mc-key-map` gets in the way.
I am using doom emacs on Mac OS.

The command to which it is bound is

```
(evil-mc-make-and-goto-first-cursor)
```

with key Bindings

```
evil-mc-cursors-map 0
evil-mc-key-map <normal-state> C-p
evil-mc-key-map <visual-state> C-p
```

Each time I manually execute the code

```
(evil-define-key 'normal evil-mc-key-map (kbd "C-p") 'org-previous-visible-heading)
(evil-define-key 'visual evil-mc-key-map (kbd "C-p") 'org-previous-visible-heading)
```

it gets overwritten, but for some reason after a new startup of emacs after Mac restart I keep getting this command bound to `evil-mc-make-and-goto-first-cursor`.

Comment: When Emacs starts up, most keymaps are constructed from scratch, so a newly started Emacs does not know anything about what you did manually in a previous session. You need to add something to your init file, so that the initialization wil be done every time you start Emacs. Look for a hook that will be run *after* `evil` has done its initialization (maybe `evil-mode-hook`? just guessing here...) and add a function that does the initializations to that hook.